# Displaying server data on angular js Grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, offline-caching

In an offline web app , I want to dispaly server data on am AngularJS grid. I have a jsfiddle example [new JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/relly/ysmg1qkt/)

it displays default data .

This code sync server

```
  $('#btnSyncServer').click(function () {
    var customers = [];
    db.linq.from(config.objectStoreName).select().then(function () {
        if (customers.length > 0) {
            var postData = { revision: parseInt(localStorage.customerRevision, 10), appID: config.appID, customers: customers };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api/service',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Revision == localStorage.customerRevision) {
                        alert('There is newer version on the server. Please Sync from server first.');
                    }
                    else {
                        syncData(data);                           
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is what I modified so far in the jsfiddle example

```
   self.readAll = function () {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: baseUrl + objectName,
            headers: anonymousToken
        }).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };


}());
```

html side :

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used`url: 'api/service',` in modifed example but it gives me 'Failed to connect.." error . It is trying to connect to local database
is there any other way to display the server data in the grid ?

Comment: Please be more specific about what the problem is. It isn't clear what *"I have to loop it somehow"* means.

Comment: I updated content including jsfiddle link